# Why am i getting an error when trying to work with ggplot in Julia?

Tags: julia, rcall

I call the ggplot package in Julia as shown in this website: https://avt.im/blog/2018/03/23/R-packages-ggplot-in-julia. I use the package as shown in that website and everything works fine.

Now i plot the average marginal effects in Julia using the `Effects` package. I want to plot it using `ggplot` here is the data i have:

```
df = effects(design, m1)
```

[image]

Here is my ggplot code and the error:

```
ggplot(df, aes(unemploy, workhours, group = sex, shape= sex, linetype=sex)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.15)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),width = 0.1,
                linetype = "solid",position=position_dodge(width=0.15))+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.15))  

UndefVarError: sex not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[131]:1
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1116
```

I tried this code before in R on the same dataframe and it worked fine, so the problem i guess is that ggplot is not reading the data as it should. Could someone help me to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link actually explains it in this small snippet:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=:x,y=:y)) + geom_line()
```

> Note that the aes function uses Julia symbols like :x to refer to data frame columns.

In your line `aes(unemploy, workhours, group = sex, shape= sex, linetype=sex)`, `sex` is treated like any other variable in Julia, specifically that Julia tries to look for the existing variable `sex` *in the code* and the object it references. It was not found in your code, hence the `UndefVarError`.

[Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) grants R's `aes` the capability to see `group=sex` and treat `sex` as a name instead of trying to evaluate it. This slightly resembles how Julia's macros work on unevaluated expressions prior to the compile phase, but R has a very different style.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am sorry but i am new to Julia and it is still a bit complicated. I am not sure that i understood you fully regarding the `group=sex`. When i remove them, the code works fine now, but i still need to include them and i am not sure that i understood how to do so according to Julia's  code language. I tried `group =:sex`, but that did not work.

Comment: I didn't say it outright and perhaps I should have. Make this edit to the `aes` call: `aes(unemploy, workhours, group = :sex, shape= :sex, linetype=:sex)`

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! last time to bother you with this, but i am trying to change the scale in this graph by including this code as i usually do in R: `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40), breaks = seq(0, 40, by = 2))`, i get the following error:
`UndefVarError: c not defined
`. I tried to tweak by puting the double dots `:` operator, but it does not work.

Comment: When people have another question, I would normally suggest that they do it in a separate post instead of attaching it to a previous question. But I have a different suggestion: do some reading on how to code in Julia. I'm sure there are even some articles just for translating from R to Julia, start there. Your error there is because `c` isn't a combined vector function in Julia. And why would it be? Julia and R are different languages, so you shouldn't expect Julia's compiler to understand R code or for R and Julia to be designed the same way.

Comment: I will also link this bit in the Julia docs that lists differences to R. I wouldn't suggest starting there because it's not organized with examples as Julia tutorials, but it does point out how the languages "constructs vectors" among other common habit traps (docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/…)